# Editing the DataSource of a ComboBox

Tags: c#

I have a ComboBox with its DataSource set to an instance of a DataTable. When rows are added to the DataTable, they show in the ComboBox without additional code, but when a row is deleted, the ComboBox remains unchanged. A short summary of my code:

```
ComboBox selector = new ComboBox();
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

PopulateTable()
{
    DataRow row1 = tbl.NewRow();
    row1["field1"] = 1;
    row1["field2"] = "Some Text";
    tbl.Rows.Add(row1);

    DataRow row2 = tbl.NewRow();
    row2["field1"] = 2;
    row2["field2"] = "More Text";
    tbl.Rows.Add(row2);
}

PopulateSelector()
{
    selector.DisplayMember = "field2";
    selector.ValueMember = "field1";
    selector.DataSource = tbl;
}

RemoveRow()
{
    tbl.Rows[0].Delete();
}
```

At this point, the ComboBox *appears* to be correct, but clicking it resets it to its previous data. The DataTable remains correct, deleting the row causes no problem in that instance, I just can't make the ComboBox reflect the changes.

Comment: There is no combobox in the posted code.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include it. It's the object named `selector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
PopulateSelector()
{
    selector.DataSource = null;
    selector.DisplayMember = "field2";
    selector.ValueMember = "field1";
    selector.DataSource = tbl;
}

RemoveRow()
{
    tbl.Rows[0].Delete();
    PopulateSelector()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [bindingsource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) inbetween the datatable and the combobox and call ResetBindings